# A question on probability and free fall

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, probability, free-fall

An object in free-fall drops from rest. The origin is at the starting point and the $y$-axis points downwards. The $y$-coordinate of the ball is,

$$ y = \frac{1}{2} g t^2$$

The total time of flight is $6$ $seconds$.

**Question:** What is the probability that the object is in between $y = \frac{1}{2} g$ and
$y = 2 g$ *metres*?

I can think of two answers,

1. Since $y$ takes every value between $0$ and $18 g$, $$ P(\frac{1}{2} g < y < 2g) = \frac{1}{12}$$
2. $\frac{1}{2} g < y < 2g$ $\implies$ $1 < t < 2$seconds. $$P(\frac{1}{2} g < y < 2g)=\frac{1}{6}$$

*Which of these is true, and why the other isn't?*

**Edit**: This question was asked to clarify a doubt that I had in Example problem 1.2 in Griffiths QM.
*Suppose someone drops a rock off a cliff of height $h$. As it falls, I snap a million photographs at random intervals. On each picture, I measure the distance the rock has fallen. Question: What is the average of all distances? That is to say, what is the time-average of the distance travelled?*

It was necessary to calculate the probability density $\rho (y)$ to obtain the time-average distance. To do that, we needed to know *the probability that the rock is in between a distance $y$ and $y+dy$ from the start.*
There is my confusion: would this probability be $\frac{dy}{h}$ or $\frac{dt}{T}$ where $dt$ and $T$ are the time corresponding to heights $dy$ and $h$.

Comment: You are using the word "probability" but do you actually mean the amount of time the object spent between $y = \frac{1}{2} g$ and $y = 2g$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question as given is incomplete and unanswerable.  As [de Finetti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bruno_de_Finetti) famously put it: [probability does not exist](https://faculty.fuqua.duke.edu/%7Ernau/definettiwasright.pdf), at least not in the same way that mass and time and acceleration exist.

From a frequentist viewpoint, the collective (or ensemble) has to be defined.  From a Bayesian perspective, the prior has to be specified.

If the question is expanded to 'At some time $t$ chosen at random during the fall, what is the probability $g/2 < y < 2g$' then the question is valid and the answer is 1/6.

If it is expanded to 'At some position $y$ chosen  at random during the fall, what is the probability $g/2 < y < 2g$' then the question is valid and the answer is 1/12.

Other forms of expansion are possible (e.g. "At some time $t$ chosen at random between 0 and 10 seconds...")   But without this extra detail there is no single answer.

Comment: *The question as given is incomplete and unanswerable* Then why answer it anyway?

Comment: This answers the question in my mind. I wrote the exact same probabilities above, however I couldn't make up **why these two probabilities had to be different**. After all, random selection of $t$ amounts to selecting a point $y$ randomly, so why should they be different?

Answer (score 2):

Let me first note that $y=\frac{1}{2}g$ and $y=2g$ does not really make sense, since $y$ and $g$ have different dimensions (length vs. length/time squared). But I suppose that here by $g$ they mean $9.8$ meters (or whatever units of length they use).

The probability of finding the object between two heights is the time it spends between these heights vs. the total time of observation (which is here likely assumed to be the total time of flight). The answer is dependent on the height from which the object was released (which could be more than $2g$): you need to calculate the time when it reaches height $2g$ and the time when it reaches $g/2$, subtract the former from the latter, and divide by the total time of flight from the initial height to the ground.

Comment: I have additional question if we want to test it then how will we do it ? By releasing the ball by not telling the observer the time ask him to observe it according to his will randomly

Comment: @sheltonBenjamin One could made a window in a wall, between the two heights, so that observer can see the ball only through this window. Then the room is darkened and the light is randomly turned on for a short time between the moments when the ball is released and the moment when it touches the ground. And the observer reports whether they have seen the ball while the light was on. This is to repeat many times - depending on the precision required. The problem is that human reaction time is too slow to make this experiment in a room...

Answer (score 1):

The question is unclear, but I assume it means "A time $t$ is picked at random with a uniform distribution between $0$ and $6$ seconds. What is the probability that at time $t$ the $y$ co-ordinate of the ball is between $4.9$ and $19.6$ metres."

Since the ball spends $1$ second in the given space, the answer should be $\frac 1 6$.

To test this you will need some method of generating a large number of times with a uniform distribution and then recording the position of the ball at each time. Simply letting an observer pick times "at random" is unlikely to produce a uniform distribution.